Redis error in restify server (azure webapp)
I'm having this error using restify and redis on Azure:
redis Application has thrown an uncaught exception and its terminated Error read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead(node:internal/stream_base_commons)

I have this mini web app made with restify, which expose just three endpoints. Those endpoints will get the redis client and then proceed doing stuffs.. this is how I create the server:
const corsMiddleware = require("restify-cors-middleware2");

const cors = corsMiddleware({
  origins: ["*"],
  allowHeaders: ["*"],
  exposeHeaders: ["*"],
});

const serverApiKey = process.env.API_KEY;
if (!serverApiKey) {
  console.log("API_KEY not set");
  process.exit(1);
}

const alignRedisApiKey = process.env.ALIGN_REDIS_API_KEY;

// Create HTTP server.
const server = restify.createServer();

server.pre(cors.preflight);
server.use(cors.actual);

server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());
const port = process.env.PORT ?? 3978;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`\nApp Started, ${server.name} listening to ${server.url}`);
});

Those instead, are the redis methods:
// Get the Redis client to interact with the cache using host name and access key
const getRedisClient = () => {
  const redis = require("redis");

  // Environment variables for cache
  const cacheHostName = process.env.REDIS_HOST_NAME;
  const cachePassword = process.env.REDIS_ACCESS_KEY;

  if (!cacheHostName || !cachePassword) {
    console.log("Cache configuration not found");
    return null;
  }

  return redis.createClient({
    // redis for TLS
    url: `redis://${cacheHostName}:6380`,
    password: cachePassword,
  });
};

// Retrieve member from Redis cache from its email
export async function getMemberFromRedis(email: string) {
  if (!email) return null;

  const cacheConnection = getRedisClient();
  if (!cacheConnection) return null;

  try {
    await cacheConnection.connect();
    const member = await cacheConnection.get(email);
    cacheConnection.disconnect();

    return JSON.parse(member);
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error(ex);
    cacheConnection.disconnect();

    return null;
  }
}

What am I doing wrong? I think it's crashing (and I see the console error on Azure) when it tries to connect to Redis.. Assuming that Redis is working (we tested it, pinged and it works), am I doing something wrong connecting to redis in my syntax? is there another way to connect other than TCP? are there alternative ways to connect?
